# Trouble mocking singleton for unit testing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xctest

Hello I am trying to mock one of the singletons I use to test that various view controllers actually call properly it's methods.

I have the singleton declared as such

```
public class ModelsManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ModelsManager()
    private init() {}

    [...]
}
```

In the view controllers that use the singleton, it is set to a lazy computed property as such:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var Models = {
        return ModelsManager.sharedInstance
    }()

    [...]
}
```

I am trying to mock the ModelsManager singleton in my XCTestCase as such:

```
[...]

func testSomething() {
   let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "MyView", bundle: nil)
   var mockModelsManager = ModelsManagerMock.sharedInstance
   vc.Models = mockModelsManager

   [... do something that calls a function in ModelsManager...]

   expect(mockModelsManager.flag) == true // Using Nimble here
}

class ModelsManagerMock: ModelsManager {
    var flag = false

    override func test() {
        flag = true
    }
}
```

In the `expect()` assertion I am getting `Value of type 'ModelsManager' has no member 'flag'`

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
It appears that what I was missing was `ModelsManagerMock.sharedInstance` still returns `IRModelsManager()` from the superclass. Due to the fact that `static` can't be overwritten by subclasses, how do I get around this?

Comment: Are you then subclassing the singleton? If you try setting it in the same class as opposed to subclassing, I think you will have better luck. Then, if you are setting it lazy in the view controller, you shouldn't need to set it again in the testSomething() method.

Comment: If I don't set it, then how will ViewController use the `ModelsManagerMock` instead?

Comment: I wouldn't subclass it like that. Your singleton method is returning an Instance of ModelsManager, not ModelsManagerMock. If you need to write this as a singleton, you will need to override the singleton method to return the proper class. In Obj-C, this was easy with instance type. I'll see if there is a way to do it in Swift.

Comment: Partially solved this by not making the `init` method of `ModelsManager` private if a pre-processor flag named TEST is true. Then instead of doing `vc.Models = mockModelsManager` I do `let mock = ModelsManagerMock(); vc.Models = mock`. I am still looking for a compile-time solution to this one if possible though...

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution must involve not subclassing your singleton. Creating a singleton with a private init method prohibits you from subclassing this method.

If the goal is to test the current functionality of the singleton, why do you want to add additional functionality to it? The key point of a singleton is that there should only ever be one. If you want to support more than one, you shouldn't make it a singleton, even if it's just for testing.

Comment: I want to test that my controller calls a specific method of my singleton. I can't think of any other way to do this other than create a mock singleton in the form of a subclass. Adding public methods and flags in the original Singleton would make it "dirty" for no apparent reason. Do you have any other suggestion on how to test this?

Comment: You can mark them as internal and use the @testable property https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html

Comment: Basically this answer says singletons are not compatible with unit tests. I disagree. The problem I see is the lazy instantiation. You can use dependency injection instead. ...or worst case, set the singleton in your viewDidLoad and then give it your mock object. For more on the dependency injection, see https://sharpfivesoftware.com/2015/02/03/testing-singletons-in-swift/.

Comment: Singletons are completely compatible with Unit Tests. It's creating a custom version of the singleton that's the problem in this case. I don't think new objects (other than the test objects themselves) should be created for any unit test, not just singletons.